If someone is irresponsible, or weak-willed “their words lack _____?
I’ve been struggling all day to find the word that I’m looking for. Some examples of how the word I’m looking for would be used:

If someone kept lying to me over and over again and now I can’t believe anything they say because they lack ____. Like their words are meaningless.
If I was trying to discipline my toddler, he wouldn’t listen to me but he would listen to his father. Because the words I’m saying would have no effect because they lack ____.
If a girl just agrees with anything that anyone says, I wouldn’t ask her for her opinion because her words are essentially meaningless, they have no ____.

Hope someone can find an appropriate word/phrase – authenticity, validity, integrity, powerless, etc. are not the words I’m looking for.

Your first two examples are not similar. Not believing someone is different from not doing what someone tells you to do.

What would help here is a detailed explanation of why you have rejected the words you did.

What causes somebody's words to be disregarded in these cases is not any quality of the words, but of the person who is uttering them (as perceived by the addressee).

If you just want to say they're meaningless, what's wrong with "they lack meaning"? If you want to say something else, what exactly?

@Mari-LouA I am not sure “irresponsible” or “weak-willed” is what the asker was going for – it seems to be more about the words not mattering.

@user3840170  Irresponsible and weak-willed are not meant to be the answers they only summarise the personalities described in the question. Words do not matter if the person behind them has a history of telling lies (first example) or of being acquiescent. (possibly example 2, but definitely example 3)

By putting in the toddler, you change what words might work here...Just so you know.

@Mari-LouA I think the question is how to describe them not mattering (the original title referred to “integrity or meaning” – but the body then clarified “integrity” is not quite it) rather than the particular reason they don’t.

@user3840170 rollback the edit. I don't mind, I just liked a tidier title.

@Mari-LouA Well, I cannot even if insisted on it, on this site I am just a pleb with measly 253 Internet points.

@user3840170  Someone else can do it then. I don't dislike the title, but I wouldn't mind if the edit was rolled back. The OP is very quiet, perhaps disappeared in the dust trail. Shame.

The first word that came to my mind is credibility (which is indeed one of the existing answers); however, that won't fit in your second example because it implies that you can't be trusted in general whereas implicitly you are having the right intention but your advice is simply not palatable to your child (for whatever reasons).
A more appropriate word which can fit in all your examples is credence.
MW:

credence
noun
1 a : mental acceptance as true or real
give credence to gossip

In your examples (1) & (3), you do not have mental acceptance of the other person's words because they don't inspire trust in you due to their past unreliable behaviour. In example (2), your child does not have mental acceptance of your words not necessarily because you have broken their trust in the past but just as a matter of taste (may be you don't sugarcoat them enough, may be something else...).
Your examples:

... someone kept lying to me over and over again and now I can’t
believe anything they say because they lack credence .
I was trying to discipline my toddler, he wouldn’t listen to me but he
would listen to his father. Because the words I’m saying would have no
effect because they lack credence (to him and not necessarily in general).
If a girl just agrees with anything that anyone says, I wouldn’t ask
her for her opinion because her words are essentially meaningless,
they have no credence.


You “can’t believe anything they say” because you lack credence.

Credibility - The quality of being believed in, or the quality of being convincing or believable. (Definitions from Oxford Languages)
(Edited in response to Lambie's comment.) This doesn't quite fit your second example, though. If the child obeys its father but not its mother, you could say that she lacks authority.

lack credibility to a toddler?

Substance is a fitting word and 'lack substance' is a common collocation also. The OED has a good definition for this sense of substance:

The quality of being substantial or of having a solid basis in fact or reality; significance, consequence; (also) steadiness, dependability, or weight of character
Oxford English Dictionary, s.v. “substance (n.), sense III.15.a,” September 2024, https://doi.org/10.1093/OED/1739552241.


Similarly, weight

Your fill-in-the-blanks want a noun, but I would suggest deploying an adjective instead:

Her words are hollow.

See:

hollow adjective
3 : lacking in real value, sincerity, or substance : false, meaningless Source:
Merriam-Webster—hollow


Or the words are vacuous.

Here are my two cents: authority
It suits the first phrase [see https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/authority]


uncountable noun
If someone has authority, they have a quality which makes other people take notice of what they say.

He had no natural authority and no capacity for imposing his will on others.

It also suits the second sentence: if he/she doesn't listen to you it means you don't have authority on him/her.

This is pretty much what I was going to say.

authority over someone, not on them.

Lacking teeth might be applicable, indicating that something carries little consequence or authority. This would fit well for the example of a child who doesn't listen to their mother, implying that nothing will happen to the child if they disobey. The mother's words lack teeth, as the child won't get "bitten" whether they listen or not. The phrase indicates more a lack of follow-through than a lack of integrity.
Another option is to say someone's words are empty, indicating that they don't carry any meaning. Oftentimes, threats or promises are described as empty, meaning that the person isn't going to follow through.

You could try the simple effect, which Merriam-Webster gives the following definition of:

power to bring about a result : influence

The content itself of television … is therefore less important than its effect …
[Current Biography]

Similarly, impact

Yes, simple and goes with all three examples.

As suggested in a comment, weight would be a pretty fitting word (Wiktionary sense 4: “(figurative) Importance or influence.”).  The usual collocation is that [someone’s] words don’t carry weight.

Weight, or "gravity" or "gravitas". All three essentially mean the same thing

@Richard Not really – each word has different connotations. This is a bit like saying “silly” and “foolish” mean the same thing – but one is innocently amusing, and the other is perilous.

I cannot think of a single word that fits all three of the examples provided in the question. For the second and third example one could say that the words lack conviction. Oxford Learner's Dictionary:

conviction noun
[...]
3. [uncountable] the quality of showing that you believe strongly in what you are saying


Significance


the quality of being worthy of attention; importance. "adolescent education was felt to be a social issue of some significance"
the meaning to be found in words or events. "the significance of what was happening was clearer to me than to her"


Definitions from Oxford Languages
